# Points and lines on a plane

Tags: combinatorics

We consider $n$ lines $l_{1},l_{2},...,l_{n}$ and a point $A$ on a plane, that does not belong to those lines. Find the number of  lines that must be drawn from point $A$ such that at least one of them intersects the $l_i$ lines in n points.

Answer (score 1):

1 line is sufficient.

Take a direction that is not parallel to any of the $n$ lines. There are infinitely many such directions available. From A, draw the line parallel to this direction. It must intersect each of the $n$ lines once, giving us $n$ points of intersection.

However, the slight issue is that the points of intersection could be repeated. This isn't a concern, as there are at most ${n\choose 2}$ intersection points between the $n$ lines, and hence at most ${n\choose 2}$ directions which we can't choose.

Hence, we still have infinitely many directions to choose from. Pick any one of them and we're done.

Comment: What if you can't choose a direction?

Comment: There are infinitely many directions that will work. Read the above.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood my question. Let me give an example. Suppose n=2. Then if the two lines are parallel to each other 2 lines must be drawn from A. If not, then you have to draw 3 lines (the 2 of them could be parallel to the lines).

Comment: if $l_1$ is parallel to $l_2$, why must we have 2 lines? From $A$, we can drop the perpendicular to these lines, and we will get 2 points of intersections.

Comment: You have to draw 2 in order to be sure that 1 of them intersects them in 2 points. Without making any statements about directions of lines.

Comment: @Matheo Ah i see. Your question should have been phased as "What is the minimum number of lines that need to be drawn, such that any combination of $N$ lines would intersect each of these lines?" Otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! You've been very helpful.